# I am having problem with the linked list. It's a snake game with doubly list and it doesn't suppose to eat, It just grow each 5 steps by 1 block

Tags: c

- I am having problem with the linked list.
- It's a snake game with doubly list and it doesn't suppose to eat, It just grow each 5 steps by 1 block.
- It's a snake game with doubly list and it doesn't suppose to eat, It just grow each 5 steps by 1 block.
  I get "Dereferencing NULL point" at the snake initial function,read access violation. snakeTailPtr was 0xCDCDCDCD. at void print function
- List item

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define ROWS 25
#define COLS 75

// terminal escape codes/ANSI escape codes (or ANSI escape sequences)
// "\x1B" is the escape character that tells your terminal that what comes next is not meant to be printed on the screen, 
// but rather a command to the terminal (or most likely terminal emulator).
// Turn escape codes ON.
// Turn escape codes ON.

typedef struct node {
    int x;
    int y;
    struct node* next;
    struct node* prev;
}NODE;

typedef struct SNAKE {
    NODE* head;
    NODE* tail;

}SNAKE;

// Moves the cursor to position (x,y) on screen.
// Parameters:
//     x: the row of the position.
//     y: the column of the position.
void gotoxy( int x, int y );

// Delays the execution of the program.
// Parameters:
//     secs: the length of the delay in seconds. 
void sleep( float secs );

//My Functions///
void init( void );
void print( SNAKE* snake );
void initialTheBoard( char board[ROWS][COLS] );//Initial the board limits and print them
void initialSnaKE( SNAKE* snake );//initial the snake in the middle
void snakeSpeed( float* delay, int counter );
void checkInput( SNAKE* snake, char* keystoke, char* lastmove, int * newX, int * newY );//Check if to change the snake direction
void SnakeMovment( SNAKE* snake, int counter, float* delay, int newX, int newY, char board[ROWS][COLS] );//move the snake
bool checkIfGameOver( SNAKE* snake, char matrix[ROWS][COLS], int newX, int newY );//check if the game is over
void GameOverPrint( char board[ROWS][COLS] );//Print game over in the middle of the screen when the player lose 
void printBoard( char board[ROWS][COLS] );

int main() {

    //variables that will be used in the game
    float delay = 1.000;
    int newX = 0, newY = 0;
    int x = ROWS / 2, y = COLS / 2, count = 0;;
    bool gameOver = false;
    char keystroke = 'd', lastmove = 'd';
    char Boardmatrix[ROWS][COLS];
    //intial the snake and put him in the middle
    SNAKE* snake = (SNAKE*)malloc( sizeof( SNAKE ) );
    initialSnaKE( snake );
    initialTheBoard( Boardmatrix );
    //The Game
    while ( gameOver == false )
    {
        init();
        printBoard( Boardmatrix );
        print( snake );
        count++;
        _kbhit();
        keystroke = _getch();
        checkInput( snake, &keystroke, &lastmove, &newX, &newY );
        gameOver = checkIfGameOver( snake, Boardmatrix, newX, newY );
        SnakeMovment( snake, count, &delay, newX, newY, Boardmatrix );
        snakeSpeed( &delay, count );
        sleep( delay );
    }
    GameOverPrint( Boardmatrix );
}

void initialSnaKE( SNAKE* snake )//maybe x,y of tail need to be different
{
    //Snake start in the middle with the right values
    //Need to add malloc
    NODE* newNode = (NODE*)malloc( sizeof( NODE ) );
    newNode->x = ROWS / 2;
    newNode->y = COLS / 2;
    snake->head = newNode;
    snake->tail = newNode;
    snake->head->prev = NULL;
    snake->head->next = NULL;
}

void initialTheBoard( char board[ROWS][COLS] )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++ ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < COLS; j++ ) {
            board[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++ ) {
        board[i][0] = '#';
        board[i][COLS - 1] = '#';
    }
    for ( int i = 0; i < COLS; i++ ) {
        board[0][i] = '#';
        board[ROWS - 1][i] = '#';
    }
}

void printBoard( char board[ROWS][COLS] ) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++ ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < COLS; j++ ) {
            printf( "%c", board[i][j] );
        }
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}

void checkInput( SNAKE * snake, char* keystoke, char* lastmove, int* newX, int* newY )
{
    if ( *lastmove != 's' && *keystoke == 'w' ) {
        snake->head->x = snake->head->x - 1;
        *newX = -1;
        *newY = 0;
        *lastmove = 'w';

    }
    else if ( *lastmove != 'w' && *keystoke == 's' ) {
        snake->head->x = snake->head->x + 1;
        *lastmove = 's';
        *newX = 1;
        *newY = 0;
    }
    else if ( *lastmove != 'a' && *keystoke == 'd' ) {
        snake->head->y = snake->head->y + 1;
        *lastmove = 'd';
        *newX = 0;
        *newY = 1;
    }
    else if ( *lastmove != 'd' && *keystoke == 'a' ) {
        snake->head->y = snake->head->y - 1;
        *lastmove = 'a';
        *newX = 0;
        *newY = -1;
    }
    else {
        if ( *lastmove == 'a' ) {
            snake->head->y = snake->head->y - 1;
            *newX = 0;
            *newY = -1;
        }
        if ( *lastmove == 'd' ) {
            snake->head->y = snake->head->y + 1;
            *newX = 0;
            *newY = 1;
        }
        if ( *lastmove == 'w' ) {
            snake->head->x = snake->head->x - 1;
            *newX = -1;
            *newY = 0;
        }
        if ( *lastmove == 's' ) {
            snake->head->x = snake->head->x + 1;
            *newX = 1;
            *newY = 0;
        }
    }
}

void SnakeMovment( SNAKE* snake, int counter, float* delay, int newX, int newY, char board[ROWS][COLS] ) {
    /*
    if (counter < 5) {
        print(snake);

    }*/
    //else {

    NODE* newHead = (NODE*)(malloc( sizeof( NODE ) ));
    NODE* oldHead = (NODE*)(malloc( sizeof( NODE ) ));
    newHead->x = snake->head->x + newX;
    newHead->y = snake->head->y + newY;
    oldHead = snake->head;
    snake->head = newHead;
    snake->head->next = oldHead;
    oldHead->prev = snake->head;
    board[snake->head->x][snake->head->y] = '@';

    /*
                if (counter % 5 != 0) {
                    board[snake->tail->x][snake->tail->y] = ' ';
                    NODE* oldTail;
                    oldTail = snake->tail->prev;
                    snake->tail->prev = oldTail->prev;
                    free(oldTail);
                }
                print(snake);
            }*/
}

void snakeSpeed( float *delay, int counter )
{
    if ( *delay > 100 && counter % 5 == 0 )
    {
        *delay -= (float)0.300;
    }
}


// Turn escape codes ON.
void init( void ) {
    system( "cls" );
}




bool checkIfGameOver( SNAKE* snake, char matrix[ROWS][COLS], int newX, int newY )
{
    int theX = snake->head->x, theY = snake->head->y;
    if ( matrix[theX + newX][theY + newY] != ' ' ) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

void print( SNAKE* snake ) {
    NODE* snakeTailPtr = snake->tail;
    while ( snakeTailPtr != NULL ) {
        gotoxy( snakeTailPtr->x, snakeTailPtr->y );
        snakeTailPtr = snakeTailPtr->prev;
        printf( "@" );
    }
}


void GameOverPrint( char board[ROWS][COLS] )//need to add board clean
{
    initialTheBoard( board );
    char gameOverMessage[10] = "Game Over";
    int j = 0;
    int middleCol = (COLS / 2);
    for ( int i = middleCol - 4; i <= middleCol + 4; i++ ) {
        board[ROWS / 2][i] = gameOverMessage[j];
        j++;
    }
    printBoard( board );
    for ( int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++ ) {
        printf( "\n" );
    }

}

// Moves the cursor to position (x,y) on screen.
// Parameters:
//     x: the row of the position.
//     y: the column of the posiiton.
void gotoxy( int x, int y ) {
    printf( "\x1b[%d;%df", x, y );
}


void sleep( float secs ) {
    clock_t clocks_start = clock();

    while ( clock() - clocks_start < secs * CLOCKS_PER_SEC );
}
```

Comment: You need to learn to use a debugger. This may also help: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Stack Overflow isn't intended for you to dump your whole program and expect someone else to find all the bugs for you. Some kind people may point out some of your issues but it is much better for you to learn to debug effectively yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I used a debugger for almost a day but I can't figure out what these two error are.I added to whole code just so the logic of the function will be more clear.

Comment: Then reduce your problem and ask one question at a time. For example, focus on this issue: " I get "Dereferencing NULL point" at the snake initial function". That would be more sensible than just dumping the whole program and essentially saying "find all the problems". For that one problem be clearer in describing what is the "snake initial function" and show the exact stack trace. That's good not only for Stack Overflow but for your own debugging. Fix one small problem at a time. Shouldn't really write all that code and then go back to find out the intialise function doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the debugger on your program, I discovered the problem is in the function `SnakeMovement`.

In that function, you initialize the struct member variables `x`, `y` and `next` of `newHead`, but you don't initialize the struct member variable `prev`. That is why it has the uninitialized value of 0xCDCDCDCD when it is later accessed in the function `print`, which causes an access violation when it is dereferenced. You probably want to initialize this variable with the value NULL in the function `SnakeMovement`, so that your loop in the function `print` can detect that the end of the list has been reached.

Also, the following lines of your function `SnakeMovement` create a [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak):

```
    NODE* oldHead = (NODE*)(malloc( sizeof( NODE ) ));
    [...]
    oldHead = snake->head;
```

First, you assign the address of the dynamically allocated memory to `oldHead`, but then you overwrite that variable with some other value, so that the allocated memory will never be freed (or even used). If you never need the memory, then you should not allocate it.

Comment: Thanks for your help,Realy helped a lot.It's actually work now.
In term of efficient Cases are better than if loops with kbhit?

Comment: @Disvsros: Have you now also solved the problem of the snake only moving when you press a key?

Comment: @Disvsros: With "Cases", do you mean switch/case? I don't understand how they can be used together with `_kbhit()`? However, I guess they could be used for reading the input key (i.e. arrow key) after calling `_getch()`. Switch/case is more efficient than several if... else if.

Comment: @Disvsros: Your function `checkInput()` would be more efficient if you could use a switch/case construct instead of many if...else if. However, if that is not easy, then I wouldn't worry about it for now. The most important thing is that your program works, you can optimize it later.

Comment: Yes again realy thanks for your help I realy appreciate that. 
I changed it to switch/cases
And I made a if function that if(_kbhit()) {......}   else{ if(*lastmove a){....} if(*lastmove d){....} if(*lastmove s){....} if(*lastmove ==w){....}}
What I did wrong is that I didn't put it in term if someone hit a key so it always waited for some one to hit the key.

Comment: actually I dont think I even need the Else function since the direction newX,newY ,lastmove pointers  will have the same value as before

Comment: @Disvsros: Yes, it is nice when a program finally works. Regarding the previous problem you were having which you were unable to solve with the debugger: Were you now able to see what was going on in the debugger? Or did you just fix the bug without looking at the debugger to see what exactly was going on? Being able to understand the debugger is very important. For example, do you know how to watch the values of variables while running through a program line by line?

Comment: I used the debugger for awhile before I asked help on this forum.
I gave it another try and worked on it another 1-2 hours with the debugger than I went and draw on board the whole logic behind that nodes connections than I understood my whole logic understanding was wrong. In my mind I acted like it's a normal link list Insted of doubly linked list. I still had some bugs after that but I solved it all with the debugger.

Comment: @Disvsros: That's good. The debugger is very useful for such things.